# Capistrano-resque commands not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've installed resque-scheduler, but for some reason when I try to run the

```
bin/cap production -vT | grep resque
```

I get nothing.

First I have a hypothesis, in my unicorn.rb I have:

```
root = "/opt/www/mk/current"
working_directory root
pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.mk.sock"
worker_processes 1
timeout 30
```

could the problem be that worker_processes is 1?

Now I have my resque.rake here:

```
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque/scheduler/tasks'

namespace :resque do
  task :setup do
    require 'resque'
    Resque.redis = ENV['REDIS_SERVER']
  end
  task :setup_schedule => :setup do
    require 'resque-scheduler'
    Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/resque_schedule.yml")
  end

  task :scheduler_setup => :setup_schedule
end
```

My Capfile:

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Include default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rails'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
require 'capistrano-resque'
```

and my deploy.rb here where the environmental variable links to my remote

```
set :application, 'mk'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:user/mk.git'
set :deploy_to, '/opt/www/mk'
set :user, 'deploy'
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets}

role :db, ENV['DATABASE_URL']
role :resque_worker, ENV['RAILS_SERVER']
role :resque_scheduler, ENV['RAILS_SERVER']

set :workers, {
  "auto_queue" => 1,
  "cleanup_queue" => 1,
  "follower_ids_queue" => 1, 
  "remove_ids_queue" => 1,
  "favorite_queue" => 1
}

namespace :deploy do

  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc 'Manage Unicorn'
    task command do
      on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 1 do
        execute "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{fetch(:application)} #{command}"
      end      
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

end
```

As I said if I try to execute a bin/cap command where the stage is production all it does when I push enter is nothing, it just goes to the next line.

Comment: Have you require your task in `deploy.rb`?

Comment: I have require 'resque/tasks' in my resque.rake file if that's what you mean?

Comment: no it is not what i mean. Show your `deploy.rb` please.

Comment: what the capistrano version? Are you using multistage feature?

Comment: capistrano 3.4, not using any features as far as I know